# Is there a test of monotony, convexity or concavity?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have a problem that I don't think I've met before.
I have N observations of the variables v1 and v2 and I assume that there is a function f such as v2 = f(v1).

I want to know if f has a particular 'statistical' monotony (increasing or decreasing) and if it is 'statistically' convex or concave.
By 'statistical' I mean that my observations may include error terms so you may encounter pairs of variable that show a monotony that is the opposite of the global monotony, if that's English.

Should I simply compute a f' and a f'' ? (derivatives of f).

If you have some thoughts on this I'd be glad to read it.
Thanks,

Arthur

(btw I use Stata)

Comment: You need more assumptions.  After all, you could regress v2 against v1 to estimate a *linear* function, which is guaranteed monotonic (and both convex and concave).

Comment: [Here is a paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-29/issue-1/Multiscale-Testing-of-Qualitative-Hypotheses/10.1214/aos/996986504.full) that gives minimax test for this problem.