# Using Jensen's Inequality to identify blackbox function as convex?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, probability-inequalities, convex

** Edits:

In light of the comments I received: I'll appreciate any elaboration on the questions I present. If you can provide examples of what I would need (assumptions, test cases, etc), books/websites to read through, and any additional insight that could help guide my research, I'll take that as an answer.

** Original questions

I've been doing some reading on Jensen's Inequality. I'm a graduate engineering student, but basically a novice in stats. Say I have a computer program that evaluates some unknown, continuous, differentiable function, $f$. I want to know whether that function is convex or not. All I can do is provide inputs to the program, and receive the outputs. Let's say the inputs are uniformly distributed (randomly generated) numbers within some interval $[a,b]$, and that $f$ is bounded within that interval.

e.g.

$$
y = f(x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_m)
$$
$$
x_i \in [a_i,b_i],  \forall i
$$

I know I should be able to use Jensen's Inequality to test the hypothesis that the function is convex.... BUT, my conclusion should have some probability associated with it, right? In other words, I can't prove that my hypothesis is valid without testing infinitely many points. So if I have a finite sample of points of size N, and the function is m-dimensional, then my result should be "hypothesis is valid with z% confidence," right? If my sample is really small, I should have little confidence in the validity of my hypothesis.

So my questions are:

1. How do I determine the sample size needed to test my hypothesis that a function is convex over a given interval?
2. How should the sample size vary with function dimension in order to achieve the desired confidence?

And to complicate things further, consider two functions:

(a) $y = x^2$

(b) Griewank's Function: $y = 1 + \left(\frac{1}{4000}\right)\sum_{i=1}^{m} x_i^2+\prod_{i=1}^{m}cos(\left(\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{i}}\right))$

Say, for example, they're 1-dimensional. If the interval I sample on is large enough (e.g. [-1000,1000]), and my sample size is 50 points, there is a REALLY high probability that both functions will appear to be convex.

The last questions are:

3. I'm perfectly okay with both functions in the previous example appearing to be convex over some interval, based on some sample size. How do I determine the sample size, as a function of the interval size, in order to give me a valid hypothesis for functions that are "approximately convex"?
4. Say I sample Griewank's function twice, first over the interval [-1000,1000], and it appears convex. The second time, I sample over a smaller interval: 
   $$
   [c,d] \in [-1000,1000], s.t. d-c < 2000
   $$
   This time, the hypothesis fails. The function no longer appears convex. What statistics (standard deviation, skewness, etc.) can I use to determine the interval size at which the function no longer appears convex, or the sample size taken over the previous interval at which the function no longer appears convex?
5. Which statistics courses should I take in order to learn to do this sort of thing on my own?

Links:

[Is there a test of monotony, convexity or concavity?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12629/is-there-a-test-of-monotony-convexity-or-concavity)

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467680/jensens-inequality

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672624/optimization-jensens-inequality

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1176787/application-of-jensens-inequality?rq=1

Due to the vocabulary used in the first link, I'm making my way through that paper very slowly.

Comment: This kind of question is unanswerable without making further assumptions. In particular, to obtain a confidence interval you will need a probability model. Although that is implicit in the choice of uniformly random inputs, they cannot be converted into an appropriate probability model until more is known (or assumed) about the function. For instance, if it's not even of bounded variation, you can't say a thing. To get quantitative results I believe you will have to assume differentiability along with a universal upper bound on the magnitude of the derivative.

Comment: @whuber - I added the assumptions that f is bounded on the interval, and differentiable... Now, since I don't "know" anything about the function, let's say I get all of my information from my sample. For example, (1) I identify the largest derivative based on secant lines drawn using my sample, and assume the maximum is 10 times that value, (2) I can obviously estimate a mean from a fairly small sample, and let's say I rely on my sample variance to determine overall variation. I can even fit a distribution such as a beta distribution using the information from my sample.

Comment: @whuber - Also, let's say that I use an interpolating model (like a radial basis function) as a means of gathering additional data from my original sample. For example, if I sample 50 points on the original function, I can interpolate/regress on those points and sample another 1000.

Comment: Those added assumptions help but aren't sufficient.  A bounded differentiable function can still make arbitrarily large swings in between sample points. If you could assume a definite bound on the *derivative* (which is stronger than assuming there is *some* bound), then you would have control over how much the function could vary between sample points and that would give you something to work with.

Comment: @whuber - I was hoping to use this process in an algorithm. Each iteration, I would sample over a smaller interval. Eventually, if there are large swings in variations, one of my samples will capture it. So if I have three intervals (L,M,S) for (large,medium,small), where S is in M, and M is in L, and three samples (XL, XM, XS), XL's variation may be small, while XS is large. That tells me that the function experiences large variations over small intervals, but relatively small variations over large intervals. I hope to use var(XS) to see if var(XL) makes sense (within reason).

Comment: The difficulty is that you haven't made enough assumptions, or strong enough assumptions, to guarantee that one of your samples actually will capture the non-convexity. To establish that guarantee you need to have enough control over the function's behavior that you know it won't have some arbitrarily thin (but differentiable) spike or dip somewhere. Until you can establish something like this, it means you can't construct any useful confidence statement for your hypothesis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27247/discussion-between-eric-inclan-and-whuber).